# Change or override tab order in excel userform

Tags: vba, excel

I have a user form that has a tab order as follows,

```
txtCode
txtName
cboGrade
txtPhone
txtDormitory
cboPhase
cboCourse
cboStatus
txtGrad
txtCsd
txtSsn
txtComments
cboGender
txtADD
```

However I have a command button cmdContinue that after I hit that button I want it to go straight to "cboStatus", is there any way to add that in my code

i.e

```
Private Sub cmdContinue_click()

insert my code here

cboStatus.select
end sub
```

Is there anything that will work?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `.SetFocus`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can order by tab index property (Ex. if the TabIndex property value of cmdContinue is 10, you need to change the TabIndex property value of cboStatus to 11).

Or

you can use this code as well:

```
Private Sub cmdContinue_click()

    'insert your code here

    cboStatus.SetFocus

End Sub
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you!! That is just what I was looking for!